# SQL query on extracting data for 10 minutes interval from a table

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 columns in table which are Id(int) , Value(int) and Time(datetime). I want query that get data(s) for 1st 10 mins then 2nd set of 10 mins and continued on..

Example of data from the table

[Screenshot of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBqCt.jpg)

I tried using  this query but it display nothing

```
SELECT sensor_Id
    ,sensor_Value
    ,sensor_Timestamp
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, sensor_Timestamp, GETDATE()) <= 10
```

Comment: Do you want all records or do you want to do some sort of aggregation by 10 minute intervals?  Please include your desired output.

Comment: yes i want do the aggregation. So it will show the data for 1st set of 10 minutes.

Comment: But _how_ and _what_ do you want to aggregate?

Comment: Im not sure how to write query on it. Based on the image, it will display the ID, Value and Time from 2016-10-10 15:48:50.000 to 2016-10-10 15:49:15.000. Then i want it to display the next 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is fine, if you want to show the values from the 10 minutes immediately before the time the query was run.

If you want some *specific* 10-minute interval, you need to specify that (by passing that date & time in place of `getdate()` or by using `between` with a start and end time.

For example:

```
SELECT sensor_Id ,sensor_Value ,sensor_Timestamp
FROM TABLE where sensor_Timestamp between '2016-10-10 15:50' and '2016-10-10 16:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query will give you desired result

```
    SELECT sensor_Id, sensor_Value, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, sensor_Timestamp, 0), 101)  + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),CONVERT(DATETIME, sensor_Timestamp, 0), 108) as sensorTimestamp
FROM TABLE 
    group by sensor_Id, sensor_Value, sensorTimestamp
```

I have truncated the second digit of minute to put aggregate function on it.

Comment: did u missed putting the ' FROM Table ' ?

Comment: @Afiqah sorry, I just missed that, but I hope you are able to get desired result after adding From Table :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this (I am trying to create start and end date variables with minutes divisible by 10)

```
declare @current_time datetime = getdate()
declare @total_minutes int = datediff(minute, 0, @current_time)
declare @add_subtract_minutes int = @total_minutes % 10
declare @start_date datetime = dateadd(minute, @total_minutes - @add_subtract_minutes, 0)
declare @end_date datetime = dateadd(minute, @total_minutes + (10 - @add_subtract_minutes), 0)

SELECT sensor_Id
    ,sensor_Value
    ,sensor_Timestamp
FROM TABLE
WHERE sensor_Timestamp between @start_date and @end_date
```

Test Snapshot-
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the exact solution, you can try something like this:

```
Declare @startdatetime datetime= '2016-10-10 15:49:15.000'

Declare @executeForThisNumber int = 3 -- for 3 intervals of 10 mins after @startdatetime

While @executeForThisNumber > 0
begin
    declare @cmd varchar(max) = 'Select * from table
    Where sensor_TimeStamp > ''' + convert(varchar(40), DATEADD(mi,-10,@startdatetime), 121) + ''' AND sensor_TimeStamp <= ''' + convert(varchar(40), @startdatetime, 121) + ''''
    EXEC (@cmd)

    set @startdatetime = convert(varchar(40), DATEADD(mi,10,@startdatetime), 121)
    set @executeForThisNumber = @executeForThisNumber - 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, this should get you going. You just need to format the datetime values to truncate the last minute digit.

```
-- SET UP TEST DATA
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SensorData', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #SensorData;
CREATE TABLE #SensorData (sendor_ID int, sensor_Value int, sensor_Timestamp DATETIME);
INSERT #SensorData (sendor_ID, sensor_Value, sensor_Timestamp)
SELECT A.sendor_ID, A.sensor_Value, A.sensor_Timestamp
  FROM (
        SELECT * FROM #SensorData WHERE 1=2
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,  0001, '06/18/2020 01:01'
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,  0002, '06/18/2020 01:02'
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,  0003, '06/18/2020 01:03'
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,  0005, '06/18/2020 01:05'
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,  0008, '06/18/2020 01:08'
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,  1013, '06/18/2020 01:13'
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,  1016, '06/18/2020 01:16'
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,  2021, '06/18/2020 01:21'
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,  2027, '06/18/2020 01:27'
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,  3032, '06/18/2020 01:32'
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,  3036, '06/18/2020 01:36'
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,  4041, '06/18/2020 01:41'
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,  4047, '06/18/2020 01:47'
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,  5054, '06/18/2020 01:54'
        UNION ALL SELECT 1,  5059, '06/18/2020 01:59'
        UNION ALL SELECT 1, 20001, '06/18/2020 02:01'
        UNION ALL SELECT 1, 20002, '06/18/2020 02:02'
       ) A


-- SIMPLY RETURN THE DATA AND CHANGE TIMES TO 10 MINUE INTERVALS
SELECT A.sendor_ID
      ,A.sensor_Value
      ,(CONVERT(char(15), A.sensor_Timestamp, 121)+'0')
  FROM #SensorData A

-- AGGREGATE IN 10 MINUTE INTERVALS
SELECT A.sendor_ID
      ,COUNT(*) AS LogInstances
      ,SUM(A.sensor_Value) AS Total_sensor_Value
      ,(CONVERT(char(15), A.sensor_Timestamp, 121)+'0') AS sensor_Timestamp_10min_Intervals
  FROM #SensorData A
 GROUP BY A.sendor_ID
      ,(CONVERT(char(15), A.sensor_Timestamp, 121)+'0')
 ORDER BY A.sendor_ID
      ,(CONVERT(char(15), A.sensor_Timestamp, 121)+'0')
```

Answer (score -1):

The result of DATEDIFF is a number of days ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff )

I think you can do something like that (not tested) :

```
SELECT sensor_Id, sensor_Value, sensor_Timestamp FROM Table WHERE sensor_Timestamp > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
```

Comment: The questioner asked for `SQL-SERVER`, but you are answering with `MySQL` query